What is the requirement for current to flow in a configuration made up of positive terminal connected to a conductor floating in air?
I understand, that there needs to be a potential difference and a complete circuit for current to flow.
Given that potential at a point, is the work done to a bring a unit charge, from infinity to that point, the potential at the positive terminal is let's say, $+5 \ V$.
Let's say, the conductor was initially disconnected and was floating in the air.
That makes, the potential at the connecting end of the conductor $0 \ V$, just before making the connection to the positive terminal.
When this connection is made with the positive terminal, we have a potential difference. Then, why do electrons not flow through the conductor? How does the voltage at the conductor equalize the voltage of the positive terminal, without electrons flowing?
The only explanation I could think of, was just before the time that the conductor comes in contact with the positive terminal, the voltage at the conductor, is already very close to the positive terminal, and when the connection is made they are the same potential.
Please help.

I don’t understand what you are saying. Once the initially neutral conductor is connected to the positive terminal (presumably of a battery) it has a positive potential since it now requires work to bring a positive test charge from infinity to the conductor

"Then, why do electrons not flow through the conductor?" What do you mean by this?According to standard convention electrons do flow through the conductor.

@BrendanDarrer Don’t understand your point. You can have a potential without current. The positive terminal of a battery not connected to a circuit has a potential.

$*\dots$ then why does electron not flow through the conductor?*
Electrons do flow along the conductor leaving it, and going into the positive terminal system until the potential of the conductor is at the same potential as that of the positive terminal system.
